# databricks - why I can't see the visualization icon?

Tags: databricks, visualization, dashboard

in databricks I display a df, but it only returns the result as a two dimension table, I can't see the visualization icons like below.

[image]

And I only have below icon returned.
[image]

I have import 2 plot packages.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mlt
```

how to let visualisation icons display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new implementation of visualizations is rolled out - it unifies visualizations used by Databricks SQL with visualizations in notebooks. So now you need to press on the `+` button and select `Visualization` to create a new graph.

[image]